# Fail to get all nodes under a tag with python-BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The page I am scraping is [link](http://ijcai.org/proceedings/2011). I would like to get all the `a href`s of papers. The consequent code is as below:

```
import urllib2
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get('http://ijcai.org/proceedings/2011')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
page = soup.find('div', class_ ='field-item even')
tree = [child for child in page.children]
```

But when I tried:`tree[-1]`, I got:

```
<a href="Erratum049.html">Erratum</a>
```

Indeed it just laid on the half of the page. When did I fail to get the remaining parts of that page? Do you have any ideas about it? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML of this page is *not well-formed*, use a [different parser](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers), e.g. `html5lib`  (requires `html5lib` to be installed):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html5lib')
```

or `lxml` (requires `lxml` to be installed):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
```

Now `tree[-1]` would be the last paragraph on the page:

```
<p><a href="http://ijcai.org/Proceedings/11/Papers/507.pdf">Index</a> / 2871</p>
```

---

I would also improve the way you extract the links:

```
links = [a["href"] for a in soup.select(".field-item a")]
```